# xp_cmdshell user is not listing newly created user "CustomUserX"

Tags: sql-server, powershell, t-sql, sql-scripts

I am trying to execute a powershell script from within an AFTER UPDATE SQL TRIGGER. From a component perspective the UPDATE and powershell cmd appear to function properly. However, the TRIGGER script as a whole fails at the point of executing the powershell script.

I recently discovered that to execute xp_cmdshell, it needs a user proxied to a windows account. Makes sense as anything executed outside of the SQL space needs a windows account to do so.

I then proceeded (after some research) to create the proxy user using the steps as follows

```
/* Enable xp_cmdshell */
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

/* Target DB */
USE master

/* Created a custom user with pwd */
CREATE LOGIN CustomUserX WITH PASSWORD = 'strong_password'

/* Created a user from the login */
CREATE USER CustomUserX FROM LOGIN CustomUserX

/* Granted execute for CustomUserX */
GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_cmdshell TO CustomUserX

/* Created proxy user using local machine account and pwd */
EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'LOCALMACHINENAME\WinsAccount','pwd'

/* Execute as login CustomUserX */
EXECUTE AS login = 'CustomUserX'

/* Ran simply listing of contents of drive E:/ */
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'DIR E:\*.*'
REVERT
```

When I tried to execute the script from with the trigger, the trigger failed with.

```
SQL Server Database Error: The server principal "CustomUserX" is not able to access the database "AnotherDB1" under the current security context.
```

I ran `exec ex_cmdshell 'echo %username%` only to discover the "CustomUserX" account is not listed (only SQL$.., and NULL).

The above proxy scripts were executed for the master table as suggested. Would I need to do the same thing under the db instance ("AnotherDB1") as well?

Comment: you need to grant the user to use the database https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-database-permissions-transact-sql

Comment: Thanks @maSTAShuFu I physically double checked the db security and noticed that the target db (for some reason) did not have the user and the required credentials added. I forgoed on the script and just added the principle user manually. Now my issue is with either table lock timeouts, recursions (although doubtful) or both. I'll open a separate thread for that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to grant the user to use the database

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-database-permissions-transact-sql